# Parse error where the dates fail to convert to the correct format

Tags: r, parsing

Hi Everybody I am working in R and loaded a CSV file that has the date column. When trying to change the column where the dates are from characters to a Date format, I receive the following error
**Warning Message:
412 failed to parse.**
the data set is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXM7N.png)

when trying to convert the dataset from characters to date time format i used the following input
sleep_day$Date<- as_date(sleep_day$Date)

I have been trying to troubleshoot this for a couple of days and have been struggling as the column when checking the column to be correct in terms of formatting says yes it has been converted to the correct type, but i receive NA in all the columns. Even though the dates are consistent in terms of formatting.

Comment: Use `lubridate`: `library(lubridate)

df |> 
  mutate(SleepDay = as_date(mdy_hm(SleepDay)))`. First transfer to `dttm` then with `as_date` to date format.

Comment: Thanks for the help realized the Y in mdy needed to be capitalized as to include the full year otherwise only two number would ne included for century. below is the code that worked

Comment: daily_activity <- daily_activity %>% 
  rename(Date = ActivityDate) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))